# Phone call programmatically iOS 10.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic3, ionic-native

How can I trigger the Call button in the confirmation prompt?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:xxxxxxxxxxx"]];
```

Comment: You can't. You can't send SMS without user interaction neither.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't as that prompt is presented by iOS and the app has no access to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot.**

This would be against App Store Review Guidelines, which [clearly state](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) that it is against the review rules to modify the behaviour of prompts added for security reasons.